# JOIN without keys?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

in T-SQL (SQL Server 2008), is it technically correct to INNER JOIN two tables through key-less columns (no relationships)? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join on any two fields that have the same data (and they should be the same datatype as well).  If the fields are indexed you should not have performance issues either unless you are joining on two varchar (4000) fields. You may even need to do this when you have a poor database design and one column is serving more than one purpose espcially if you have used an EAV model.

However what you won't get in this scenario is data integrity. Without a foreign key to enforce the rules, you may find that the related table has values that don't have a match to the parent table. This could result in records not seen in queries that should be seen or records which cannot be correctly interpreted. So it is a good practice to set up foreign keys where they are applicable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. I often join child of a child table bypassing the "middle" table.

Foreign keys are constraint for data integrity: nothing to do with query formulation. You should have them anyway unless you don't care about data quality and integrity.

Answer (score 1):

It will work, it might not be very efficient though...You should definitely create the foreign keys if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it will work. No problems there.However, sometimes the query plan generator will use FK's to help make better use of indexes. But, from a design standpoint, it's not such a great idea. You should be using FK's as much as possible, especially if you want to go the ORM route.